# Pandas change from flat file to column format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks as follows

```
Data.ix[1:4]
   Open  Type     DateTime
1  3     A        2013-02-19 08:48:00
2  5     A        2013-02-19 08:50:00
3  1     B        2013-02-19 08:48:00
4  7     B        2013-02-19 10:33:00
```

I want to change this to following format:

```
DateTime              A   B      
2013-02-19 08:48:00   3   1
2013-02-19 08:50:00   5
2013-02-19 10:33:00       7
```

The dataframe is large and there are about 50 different `Types`. I want to have the `DateTime` as the new index sorted. The types for `Type` column are new columns for the result dataframe.

I don't have an idea about how to approach this. I tried using `pandas pivot table` but I don't know what to do from there.

```
z1 = pd.pivot_table(Data, index=['DateTime', 'Type'], values=['Open'], aggfunc=[np.sum])['sum']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` like the way shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
Data  = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'open':[3,5,1,7], 'Type': ['A','A','B','B'], 'DateTime' : pd.date_range("11:00", "14:00", freq="60min")})

table = pd.pivot_table(Data, values = 'open', index=['DateTime'],
                columns=['Type'])
print table
```

results in

```
Type                   A    B
DateTime                     
2017-04-19 11:00:00  3.0  NaN
2017-04-19 12:00:00  5.0  NaN
2017-04-19 13:00:00  NaN  1.0
2017-04-19 14:00:00  NaN  7.0
```

Comment: Memory Error :) .. my dataframe is so large